# Is the restriction of a paraboloid a regular surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Check if $f(u,v)=(u+u^2,v^2,v^3)$ defines a regular surface for $(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

If it was a regular surface then the jacobian of the $f$ would have rank $2$, but for $u=-\frac{1}{2}$ it fails. (Morever $f$ would need to be injective but $f(-1,0,0)=f(0,0,0).$)

The points of $f$ satisfy $x\geq-\frac{1}{4}$ and $z=y^2$. The points where $x=-\frac{1}{4}$ are the ones that fail the previous condition. I think the image of $f$ is not regular surface because the tangent plane is not defined on those points, but I do not know how to justify it rigorously.

Comment: For a point on a regular surface projection to at least one of the coordinate planes is a local diffeomorphism. You can check that this is not true for the points where $x=-1/4$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more why is not it a diffeomorphism? For instance if $S$ is the paraboloid mentioned and $V$ is neighbourhood of $(-\frac{1}{4},0,0)$ then $S\cap V$ is not supposed to be homeomorphic to any open disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$,right? I can not see the reason why..@Max

Comment: Which paraboloid? The projection to $x-y$ or $x-z$ planes has image which is half-plane and quarter-plane respectively; neither is a local diffeo to the plane for points with $x=-1/4$ (for example since the image does not include an open neighborhood around the image point). The projection to $y-z$ plane has image the parabola, and so it is nowhere a local diffeo to that plane.